# xargs: passing 'find' tests.py to manage.py test

Tags: python, django, macos, bash, nose

I try to execute following bash command in django project directory. I'm using `django-nose` as a TestRunner.

```
find . -name \tests.py -print0 | xargs -0 -Ixxx ./manage.py test xxx --settings=project_name.conf.test.settings
```

but I get following errors (depending on number of tests.py files):

```
OSError: No such file /Users/user/Projects/project_name/{}
```

The same whithout `-print0` stops on first `tests.py`

Full traceback (command whithout `-print0`:

```
nosetests --verbosity 1 ./project_name/backend/tests.py
./project_name/contrib/auth/tests.py
./project_name/frontend/tests.py
 --failed --stop --nocapture --debug=DEBUG --nologcapture
To reuse old database "test_db" for speed, set env var REUSE_DB=1.
To reuse old database "test_db1" for speed, set env var REUSE_DB=1.
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Creating schema msg
Creating schema dict
Creating test database for alias 'db2'...
Creating schema msg
Creating schema dict
E
======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: OSError (No such file /Users/user/Projects/project_name/{})
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/project_name/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/failure.py", line 39, in runTest
    raise self.exc_class(self.exc_val)
OSError: No such file /Users/user/Projects/project_name/{}

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

FAILED (errors=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
Destroying test database for alias 'db2'...
```

What is the proper way to use `xargs` in such case?

Comment: Can you give the full traceback of the OSError?

Answer (score 0):

Following command is proper:

```
find . -name \tests.py -print0 | xargs -0 -Ixxx ./manage.py test xxx --settings=project_name.conf.test.settings
```

I've just did `rm .noseids` before running it. It's always causing problems if you execute `./manage.py test` with wrong arguments. Then it's written in `.noseids` and executed every time after.